# Activate UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I'm trying to make a view load as if the users has already pressed into the `UISearchBar`. I want the `SearchController` to be loaded with the `UISearchBar` on top along with the cancel button.

I've tried this:

```
func activateSearch(){
        self.searchBarShouldBeginEditing(self.searchController.searchBar)
        self.willPresentSearchController(self.searchController)
        self.updateSearchResultsForSearchController(self.searchController)
}
```

Comment: Try setting prefilled data or set it as **firstResponder** may help to fix issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func activateSearch() {
    self.searchController.isActive = true 
    self.searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
 }
```

Comment: Just using: self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

worked

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans - happy to hear my bro, do well have a happy day

Answer (score 1):

this can be done simply by setting the `searchController` to `active` in `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        searchController.active = true
    }
```

and add this

```
func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```