# UISearchController how to activate from SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I found an integration of the uiSearchController in SwiftUI, but I don't know how to let it become active?

I found this:

I want that the searchBar becomes active when changing an Bool in the SwiftUI View with a @State for example.

If I add a Binding to the view modifier and set the isActive property of the searchController in

```
ViewControllerResolver { viewController in
    viewController.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchBar.searchController
    viewController.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

then is doesn't become active.

Im not really familiar with UIKit, perhaps anybody knows how to correctly activate the searchbar that one can start typing for a search.

```
class SearchBar: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var text: String = ""
    let searchController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        
    }
}

extension SearchBar: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        // Publish search bar text changes.
        if let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            self.text = searchBarText
        }
    }
}

final class ViewControllerResolver: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let onResolve: (UIViewController) -> Void
    
    init(onResolve: @escaping (UIViewController) -> Void) {
        self.onResolve = onResolve
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ParentResolverViewController {
        ParentResolverViewController(onResolve: onResolve)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ParentResolverViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}

class ParentResolverViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let onResolve: (UIViewController) -> Void
    
    init(onResolve: @escaping (UIViewController) -> Void) {
        self.onResolve = onResolve
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Use init(onResolve:) to instantiate ParentResolverViewController.")
    }
    
    override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        super.didMove(toParent: parent)
        
        if let parent = parent {
            onResolve(parent)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct SearchBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    let searchBar: SearchBar
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(
                ViewControllerResolver { viewController in
                    viewController.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchBar.searchController
                    viewController.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
                }
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func add(_ searchBar: SearchBar) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(SearchBarModifier(searchBar: searchBar))
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate a `UISearchBar` (which is what you're using), just do:

```
searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```

*(from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39387606/14351818))*

Now all we need to do is reference `searchController.searchBar` from the SwiftUI view. First, add a function to your `SearchBar` class.

```
class SearchBar: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var text: String = ""
    let searchController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    }
    
    /// add this function
    func activate() {
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Then, just call it. I think this is better than setting a `@State`, but if you require that, let me know and I'll edit my answer.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var searchBar = SearchBar()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: {
                searchBar.activate() /// activate the search bar
            }) {
                Text("Activate search bar")
            }
            .modifier(SearchBarModifier(searchBar: searchBar))
            .navigationTitle("Navigation View")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Press custom button to activate search bar]

Comment: Thank you really much. I tried something like this in the other classes/structs but this didnt worked. I also found how to disable it programmatically with `isactive=false`. Sometimes its easier than one think :).